# how to add single images for all versions of iphone in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, format

i am creating an app in xcode. For every versions of iphone i need to design all images in their own iphone format. is there any way to do by keeping single images for all versions of iphone?

Comment: "Format"?  It's just the size that differs, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm both a programmer and a designer.

You only have to design one image, when you export it from AI/Sketch or whatever, export different sizes for different devices, three is enough, and add suffixes of "@2x" "@3x".

Then you import it to Xcode in Assets, put each image in the right place - 1x,2x, 3x, then the magic works.